# Creating shapefile from current dataframe extents in layout view of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile

Where is the ArcGIS 10 tool for creating a shapefile from current dataframe extents in layout view?

Have looked around and the closet thing i can find is Toolbox's Grid/Strip Map Index tools under Data Drive Pages.

I just want to be able to create a **single** polygon rectangle shp file based on the data frame (in layout view) for any given scale / page setup.

Comment: are you using the mapbook tool, or just wanting to create a shp polygon for one layout view?

Comment: for just one layout view

Comment: If this is for an inset map, check out the extent indicator option in the data frame properties. If it is for other reasons, I would just write a python script for it.

Comment: How much time would it take to write a python script for this MLowry? It is for taking raster image exports from ArcGIS to AutoCad and will be needed many times in the future. I just downloaded VS Express and will give Kirk's C# a shot but working with this stuff is way beyond my knowledge base.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a tool to do this via a Toolbox in ArcGIS 10. It might be easier to use than scripting. You can download from https://github.com/nickpeihl/mapindextool. Just copy your mxd(s) into a folder and run the tool on that folder. It will create a shapefile containing all the main extents of each mxd in that folder.

Answer (score 7):

This c# code could be used to [build an add-in for Arcmap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;

namespace MainToolsAddin
{
    public class Extent2ShapefileButton : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        public Extent2ShapefileButton()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            try
            {
                var polygon = GetExtentPolygon(ArcMap.Document.FocusMap);
                //IGraphicsContainer gc = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap as IGraphicsContainer;
                //var element = new PolygonElementClass() as IElement;
                //element.Geometry = polygon;
                //((IFillShapeElement)element).Symbol = ((IDocumentDefaultSymbols)ArcMap.Document).FillSymbol;
                //gc.AddElement(element,0);
                //((IActiveView)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap).Refresh();
                WritePolygon(@"C:\projects\forums\extents.shp", polygon);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnUpdate()
        {
        }

        private void WritePolygon(string shpFilePath, IGeometry geom)
        {
            var featClass = OpenShapeFile(shpFilePath);
            if (featClass == null)
                featClass = CreateShapeFile(shpFilePath, geom);
            IFeature feat = featClass.CreateFeature();
            feat.Shape = geom;
            feat.Store();
        }
        private IFeatureClass CreateShapeFile(string shpFilepath, IGeometry geom)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(shpFilepath);
            var wsf = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory")) as IWorkspaceFactory;
            var fws = wsf.OpenFromFile(fi.DirectoryName, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
            IFieldsEdit flds = new FieldsClass();
            flds.AddField(MakeField("ObjectID", esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID,0));
            IGeometryDefEdit geomDef = new GeometryDefClass();
            geomDef.GeometryType_2 = geom.GeometryType;
            geomDef.SpatialReference_2 = geom.SpatialReference;
            var shpField = MakeField("Shape", esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry, 0) as IFieldEdit;
            shpField.GeometryDef_2 = geomDef;
            flds.AddField(shpField);
            flds.AddField(MakeField("Name", esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString, 16));
            string fcName = fi.Name;
            if (fcName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".SHP"))
                fcName = fcName.Substring(0, fcName.LastIndexOf("."));

            var fc = fws.CreateFeatureClass(fcName, flds, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");
            return fc;
        }

        private IField MakeField(string name, esriFieldType fType, int length)
        {
            IFieldEdit fld = new FieldClass();
            fld.Name_2 = name;
            fld.Type_2 = fType;
            if (length > 0 && fType == esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString)
                fld.Length_2 = length;
            return fld;
        }

        private IFeatureClass OpenShapeFile(string shpFilepath)
        {
            var wsf = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory")) as IWorkspaceFactory;

            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(shpFilepath);
            string name = fi.Name.ToUpper().EndsWith(".SHP") ? fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.LastIndexOf(".")) : fi.Name;
            string fileName = String.Format("{0}.shp", name);
            if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName,fileName)))
            {
                var fws = wsf.OpenFromFile(fi.DirectoryName, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
                return fws.OpenFeatureClass(name);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        private IPolygon GetExtentPolygon(IMap map)
        {
            // A polygon is returned since the dataframe might be rotated
            var grphCont = ArcMap.Document.PageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
            var mapFrame = grphCont.FindFrame(map) as IMapFrame;
            var av = map as IActiveView;
            var extent = mapFrame.MapBounds.Envelope;
            ISegmentCollection sc = new PolygonClass() as ISegmentCollection;
            sc.SetRectangle(extent);

            var center = ((IArea)extent).Centroid;
            var angle = -(av.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.Rotation / 180.0 * Math.PI);
            ((ITransform2D)sc).Rotate(center, angle);
            return (IPolygon)sc;                        
        }
    }
}
```

When you create a new add-in project with Visual Studio, you should see some options like this.  I'm not sure if it works with Visual Studio Express, or whether the ArcObjects SDK needs to be installed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kirk, this will be my first attempt using the new ArcGIS Add-Ins Wizard. First question, it says "1. Start Visual Studio" Where is Visual Studio? a download? I am a programming dunce so please explain gently.

Comment: I've never used it, but you should be able to download the free ("Express") version of Visual Studio [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). This [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000021w000000) says "... due to limitations in the Express versions of Visual Studio, not all features of the framework are supported in the Express editions."  They don't say _which_ features though.

Comment: okay, i downloaded the 700mb VS Express and now it is installing 3.4gb of stuff... what else is ArcGIS Add-Ins Wizard going to require?

Comment: I'm not certain, but you might need to install the "ArcObjects SDK for the Microsoft framework" too.  I have it installed on my machine.  Have never tried to create an Add-in without it though.

Comment: well i got to step 2 "Click File, select New, and click Project. The New Project dialog box opens." 
but step 3 "Under Project types, expand the Visual Basic or Visual C# project node, expand the ArcGIS node, and click Desktop Add-Ins." makes no sense... screen shot here: http://i.imgur.com/jHuJ6.png

Comment: That means you don't have the ArcObjects SDK (Software Developer Kit). It should be available on your product CD hiding in a folder called "Desktop_Install". There will be an SDK_dotnet folder which will have what you are looking for.

Comment: see updated answer.

Comment: what order are these to be opened? http://i.imgur.com/QsngP.png

Comment: service pack error: http://i.imgur.com/ijDoa.png

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic python script to create a polygon from the dataframe extent.  Adjust the variable to suit your needs.  If you just want a simple extent polygon, you can get rid of 'feat', 'scale', and 'Page'.  ('Page' will only work if you are using data driven pages).

```
doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(doc)[0] #First Dataframe
extent = df.extent
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
feat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
scale = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Page = doc.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID

# Create Extent Polygon
array = arcpy.Array()
array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
array.add(extent.lowerRight)
array.add(extent.upperRight)
array.add(extent.upperLeft)
array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,["SHAPE@","Page","Feature","Scale"])
cursor.insertRow([polygon, Page, feat, scale])
del cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [Map Extent to Polygon](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a9b032f739254ebeb6221c9294ebc886) tool:

> Creates a polygon feature from the current map extent. In layout the
>   extent will be of the map data frame, in data view it the resulting
>   extent will be of the application window extent. Data frame rotation
>   is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
#simple python script
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("path to mxd")
data_frames = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
df = data_frames[0]
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management([df.extent.polygon], r"path to file.shp")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Thank you for answering this question - could you please [edit] your answer to add some information about what it does and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

This [Create Data Frame polygon](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0dcb445291bf461bb573b1504c170e0c) tool works in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3

Load the add-in, then customize a tool bar (or create a new one) and add it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this NOAA portal with a program.
[Script - extents to shapefile](http://mapping2.orr.noaa.gov/portal/ARDTools/gistools/arcgis9xmapextent.html)
I know I have seen that somewhere. Still looking.
Here are a couple of ddp tools on the [resources center.](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing?page=4&&galleryVersion=10.0)

Comment: i used to use that one in 9.3 For some reason it does not work in 10

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do it once, you can find the extents in the Data Frame properties window. Then you can create a new shapefile, add a new feature, right-click and choose to manually enter the coordinates corresponding to the corners.

Otherwise go with the script from @artwork21.