# How do I get the extent of a rotated data frame in map units from the Layout View?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I need to get the real extent of a rotated data frame in map units from the Layout View using ArcObjects.
I've checked previous discussions on the subject:

[How do I obtain the envelope of a data frame in Layout?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29021/how-do-i-obtain-the-envelope-of-a-data-frame-in-layout)

[How can I transform layout page units to map units?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/how-can-i-transform-layout-page-units-to-map-units)

but it seems there was no final answer on how to get corner coordinates for a rotated data frame. Also, the tool provided in the above post does not recognize rotated data frames. It is a bit confusing as even if you rotate the data frame in ArcGIS, the extent, indicated in the Data Frame Properties, remains unchanged.

Is there a simple way to get the real extent directly from ArcObject, or do I need to calculate these coordinates using map scale, size of the data frame etc..? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't **ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.Extent** gives the extent of the data frame? Maybe you can go through [IActiveView.Extent Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000199000000).

Comment: Both return the unrotated envelope (i.e. same values regardless the rotation).

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get a layer's extent, that is rotated. In that way, you can go through with : http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/ComponentHelp/index.html#/AreaOfInterest_Property/00120000076m000000/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the question has already been asked: [ArcGIS 10 creating a shape file from current dataframe extents in layout view](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/arcgis-10-creating-a-shape-file-from-current-dataframe-extents-in-layout-view) and has been answered by [npeihl](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13622/4754) and [Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13603/4754). My fault I have missed it in my initial search, credits go to npeihl and Kirk.