# Creating polygon from current display extent using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, extents

I am trying to create a polygon from current display extent using Python. I would like to use the polygon to clip features in the current display extent or set a boundary limit for similar procedures.

Comment: It's really not difficult, get the extent of the data frame, make 4 points from the min/max values and feed into an array as 5 points (first is repeated as last) and then use that array to create a polygon.. see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Polygon/018z00000061000000/ (waaay down the bottom there's an example). To put this into a feature class suitable for clipping create the feature class and use an insert cursor with SHAPE@ as a field.

Comment: this question has an answer with a toolbox tool already set up to do this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/creating-shapefile-from-current-dataframe-extents-in-layout-view-of-arcmap

Comment: Thanks! my question seems to be a duplicate of the links above.

Comment: I just added an answer to that question explaining how to do it simply with Python since you were asking about python.